# Creating a Profile2 Relationship in a View blocks some non-Profile fields

Tags: views, users

I have a View of nodes where I am showing the node title, main image, taxonomy, and author. All the fields show as expected.

I need to add a field from the user's profile. So I add a Relationship to the View. Before adding any Profile fields, all the fields still display correctly.

But as soon as I add any profile field to the view, the main image and taxonomy fields no longer display, unless the node belongs to the person viewing the view (or is an Admin).[image: with profile field]

[image: without any profile fields]

Comment: you can use entity relation ship module and relate profile 2 fields with node then their is no problem in showing your result

Comment: For now, I have created a new view of the Profile fields I want, then included that view in the main view using the Views Field Views module- https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view. But I would still like to know if anyone has a better workaround or patch to fix this issue directly.